# trying to find a different way to write this code

Tags: java, if-statement

I have wrote this code and now i'm practicing and i'm trying it to write it in a different or more efficient way. Basically this code asks the user to enter a word and the second player guesses the letters of the word with 6 tries and at the end there is one last chance to guess the whole entire word. Any suggestions on how i can write this code in a simple way?

```
static int NUM_OF_TRIES = 6;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Player 1 please enter the word");
    String word = keyboard.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TRIES; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your guess please");
        String guess = keyboard.next();
        boolean a = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            if (guess.charAt(0) == word.charAt(j)) {
                System.out.println(" at position " + (j + 1));
                a = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (a) {
            System.out.println("Sorry not letter " + guess.charAt(0));
            continue;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter your last guess: ");
    String wordComp;
    wordComp = keyboard.next();

    if (wordComp.equals(word)) {
        System.out.println("You got it!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry you lost!");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: does this code working? if yes, then you may post it at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you just want it to be easier to read you can extract out the inner for loop of comparing character to a function, for readability.

Comment: the continue is not needed...the code will only tell you about one of the letters so say the word ball you will get 3 not 3 and 4

Comment: it is working but thanks for pointing out the bug

Answer (score 0):

---First of all you'll have to ensure that

```
word.length <=guess.length
```

or you'll run into an exception.--- edit: that was obv not correct

Can't test right now bc I'm on my mobile, but as far as I can see, you'll run into problems if the word to guess has the same letter multiple times, since you're breaking out of the loop after finding the equal first letter.

As mentioned in comments, the comparison could be done by a method like

```
private static List<Integer> getLetterIndices(String word, char letter);
```

Then you won't need your boolean to indicate correct guesses, but a list of indices found

And of course you can do an object oriented approach instead of the static main method (not that it's faster to implement or better performance, just for practicing), perhaps something in the lines of this:

```
public class WordToGuess{
    private Map<Character,List<Integer>> letter2indices;//...
    public WordToGuess(String word){
        parseIndices(word);
    }
    //parse indices of each letter to the map
    private void parseIndices(String word); 

    public List<Integer> getLetterIndices(char letter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a shorter version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Player 1 please enter the word");
    String word = keyboard.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TRIES; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your guess please");
        String guess = keyboard.next();
        int index = word.indexOf(guess.charAt(0));

        if (index == -1)
            System.out.println("Sorry not letter " + guess.charAt(0));
        else
            System.out.println(" at position " + (index + 1));
    }

    System.out.println("Enter your last guess: ");
    String wordComp = keyboard.next();

    if (wordComp.equals(word))
        System.out.println("You got it!");
    else
        System.out.println("Sorry you lost!");
}
```

Comment: Just want to mention that this has the same issues with for example the word 'letter' und guessed 'e' or 't' bc it just results in one place ('2'/'3') instead of all places ;)

Comment: It's true the original logic could be improved. Note, however, that the author exclusively asked for a "simple way" to write the same program logic and not for a version that would be more robust or better in any other way.